How to work with Docker Compose secrets securely
I hope you are well. I have some questions about Docker secrets:

How can I work with secrets securely using Docker Compose, given that their content is exposed in /run/secrets and can be easily accessed with cat both inside and outside the containers?

Additionally, to run as a user with minimal permissions inside the container, I need to keep the permissions of the secret files open on the host machine, because if I set them as root-only, the non-root user inside the container will not be able to read their content and the application will not be able to work with the information.
This is how I have been working with secrets in my Docker Compose.
services:
  app:
    [...]
    depends_on:
      - db
    secrets:
      - postgres_db
      - postgres_server
      - postgres_user
      - postgres_password
    [...]
    networks:
      - app_net
      - db_net
  
  db:
    image: postgres:16.3-alpine3.20
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres_db
      POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres_password
    secrets:
      - postgres_db
      - postgres_user
      - postgres_password
    [...]

secrets:
  postgres_db:
    file: ./secrets/postgres_db.txt
  postgres_server:
    file: ./secrets/postgres_server.txt
  postgres_user:
    file: ./secrets/postgres_user.txt
  postgres_password:
    file: ./secrets/postgres_password.txt


Use environment variables, like this example:
.env
# remember to set correct permissions to protect this file
SERVER='dbserver.example.com'
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD='p@$$w0rd'

docker-compose.yml
---
version: '3'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:12.16-bookworm
    container_name: postgresql
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      SERVER: ${SERVER}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}


Thank you, my friend, but I have some questions. Why use .env and not secrets? And what would be the correct permissions to protect the .env file?

@user981 set .env to 600

and, as far as using secrets vs .env, secrets appears to be designed to work with Swarm
